# Is it possible to show rsync output on a single line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, output

I have a bash script that is rsyncing a large directory and the --progress function is great, but is it possible to show all this output on a single line?  ie. as the files transfer, just spit it the --progress output onto the same line as the last, so that I can watch the progress without the screen scrolling?

Comment: Do you want [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/66803/pandya) or statics based on whole transfer in one line?

Comment: @Pandya You are correct, would like the statics based on each file, so you would see each file update on that single line.   The problem with --info=progress2 is that not all versions of rsync have this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wrapper script

Here is a draft of  a wrapper script, written in Perl, that will emulate a PTY (so rsync should behave  exactly as it would in a terminal), and parses the output so it can keep a running two-line display of the filename and transfer status. It looks like this:

```
src/test.c
    142 100%    0.19kB/s     0:00:00 (xfr#28, to-chk=0/30)
```

The first line (filename, `src/test.c`) will change depending on the current filename output by `rsync`. The 2nd line will change whenever `rsync` outputs an updated status line.

**N.B.:** I opted for a 2-line display (yet one that will still not scroll!) instead of a 1-line display, as at least in my  typical usage, I end up with long path/filenames that would be too wide when combined with the status line. However, as you'll see below, it would be easy to modify to combine the file/pathname and status into one line.

When `rsync` exits, the script exits with the same exit code (so you can still trap errors, etc.)

### Rationale

Based on discussions with the OP, built-in `rsync` options were inadequate, their version of `rsync` is older, and their needs are unique. Thus, I felt that a custom script was the only way to accomplish their goal.

Other options would be to use any of the many existing `rsync` "backup" wrapper utilities already out there, although I am not aware of any that support similar output.

### Source code

```perl
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

 # Custom progress wrapper for rsync

 use 5.012;
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use autodie;
 use IPC::Run qw/run start pump finish harness/;

 my $RSYNC=`which rsync`; # Try to get rsync location from PATH
 chomp $RSYNC;

 my ($in,$out); # Input and output buffers
 my $h = harness [ $RSYNC, @ARGV ], '<pty<', \$in, '>pty>', \$out;

 local $| = 1; # Autoflush output
 print "\n\n\e[2A\e[s"; # Make room and save cursor position
 my ($file, $status) = ('',''); # Will hold filename and status lines

 while ($h->pump) { parse() }
 parse(); # Don't miss leftover output

 $h->finish;
 exit $h->result; # Pass through the exit code from rsync

 # Parse and display file/status lines from rsync output
 sub parse {
     for (split /[\n\r]+/, $out) {
         $file = $_ if /^\S/;
         $status = $_ if /^\s/;
         print "\e[u\e[0J$file\n$status\n";
     }
     $out = ''; # Clear output for next pump
 }
```

### Prerequisites

The script requires two non-standard modules: `IPC::Run`, and `IO::Pty`. Both of these can be installed with `cpan`, which comes with Perl. Many, including me,  prefer `cpanm`, which can be installed with the following one-liner:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

Then, you would run:

```
cpanm IPC::Run IO::Pty
```

#### Supported terminal types

This will work in practically *any* modern terminal, as it uses simple ANSI cursor movement and clearing codes to continually overwrite the bottom few lines of the screen.

### Usage

Same as `rsync` itself. Note that you need to specify `--progress`  yourself, but you could easily edit in some default arguments by changing the `$h = harness ...` line:

```
 my $h = harness [ $RSYNC, '--progress', @ARGV ], '<pty<', \$in, '>pty>', \$out;
```

#### `rsync` binary location

The script attempts to determine the `rsync` binary's location automatically with `which`, which will work in nearly all environments. You can also edit the `my $RSYNC='...'` line to specify a custom location if desired or required **(important:** change the backticks (`) to single quotes(') in that case.)

### Troubleshooting / extending

Error output is not specifically handled, but could be, with some minor modifications to the script.

While reasonably robust, this is obviously a "quick" effort that cannot account for all possible outputs from the incredibly complex `rsync` utility. You may need to adapt it to suit your needs somewhat, which is hopefully reasonably straightforward: all of the output comes into the `$out` variable, which you can process according to your needs.

#### Conversion to 1-line display instead of 2-line display

As mentioned above, I opted for a 2-line *non-scrolling* display to better accommodate long pathnames. However, converting the output to a 1-line display is trivial. Simply change the `print ...` line in the `parse()` sub to something like this:

```
    printf "\e[u\e[0J%-30.30s %s\n", $file, $status;
```

or, to do away with ANSI movement codes altogether:

```
    printf "\r%-30.30s %-40.40s", $file, $status;
    STDOUT->flush; # $| = 1 won't help you here
```

Then you'll see something like this instead:

```
src/test.c               142 100%    0.19kB/s     0:00:00 (xfr#28, to-chk=0/30)
```

You might notice that the `%-30.30s` is a rather arbitrary [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) width, and you'd be right. You can employ something like the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782107/how-do-i-retrieve-the-terminal-width-in-perl) to get the terminal width so you can grow/shrink that size accordingly.

Comment: I realize this is probably a much more complicated answer than you were expecting! However, based on our discussions, I believe it is the best way to meet your specific goal. I've decided to post this as a second answer, as my far simpler [first answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252874/93342) might prove useful to others with similar questions, even though it unfortunately missed the mark for you.

Comment: Appreciated the effort with Perl and...

Comment: I used `cpan` instead of `cpanm`. I'm not sure what is the difference, but I noticed that while installing `IPC::Run` the install script was looking for `IO::Pty` and couldn't find it. So maybe it would be advisable to put `IO::Pty` in front of `IPC::Run`. Other than that: Following these instructions was more than worth my while.

Answer (score 2):

I have a generic bash script `oneline` into which I pipe stuff I want to scroll into one line:

```
#!/bin/bash
cr=`tput cr;tput el`
if [ -z "$COLUMNS" ]
then COLUMNS=80
fi
while read line
do    echo -n "$cr${line:0:$COLUMNS}"
done
echo
```

The `tput` is to get the codes for carriage return and *clear to end of line* so short lines dont leave junk from previous long lines on the screen. 
Note, if your command is outputting to stderr you would need to redirect it to stdout before the pipe. eg `mycommand 2>&1 | oneline`.

Comment: This is nice script, although there's a problem: many utilities notice whether they are outputting to a terminal, and alter their behavior if not. Notably, many of them will buffer their output if their output is redirected, which can result in very long delays between updates (or, only seeing output after the command exits). Unfortunately, **`rsync` is one of them.** When I tested your utility with rsync, I got lines in big batches, many seconds apart. There are a few ways you could modify your script to fake a pty, though.

Comment: @type_outcast One hack to handle stdio buffering is to try `stdbuf -oL rsync ...|oneline`, which I think works in this case.